# Tensorflow - Dst tensor is not initialized

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I’m trying to train a convolutional neural net and am running into some issues with tensorflow. My process is being killed and the following error is thrown:

```
2018-03-14 15:56:57.850610: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1142] Internal: Dst tensor is not initialized.
    /var/spool/slurmd/job06322/slurm_script: line 23: 416703 Killed
```

After looking up the issue, I see that it’s memory related. The node in the cluster has a gpu partition with 93GB of RAM. So, it seems kinda odd that there is a memory issue. 
I think there’s an error with the way that I am splitting my dataset, but I’m not really sure. I included a code snippet about what I’m doing below. If I should provide any other information about the data that I am working with that would help with figuring out the issue, I can provide it.

```
comments = pd.read_csv('set1.tsv', sep = '\t', index_col = 0)
annotations = pd.read_csv('set2.tsv',  sep = '\t')
labels = annotations.groupby('rev_id')['score'].mean()
labels = pd.DataFrame(data=labels.values, columns=['score'])
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
labels = 1-(scaler.fit_transform(labels))
comments['score'] = labels
comments['comment'] = comments['comment'].apply(lambda x: x.replace("NEWLINE_TOKEN", " "))
comments['comment'] = comments['comment'].apply(lambda x: x.replace("TAB_TOKEN", " "))
comments = comments.reset_index()
vocab_size = 20000
max_length = 300  # max length of the comments in the model
tok = Tokenizer(num_words=vocab_size)  # make the Keras tokenizer
tok.fit_on_texts(comments['comment'])  # fit it to comments
train = comments.query("split=='train'")
test = comments.query("split=='test'")
x_train = pad_sequences(tok.texts_to_matrix(train[['comment']], mode='count'), maxlen=max_length, padding='post')
y_train = np.array([[float(d)] for d in train[['score']].pop('score')]).T
x_test = pad_sequences(tok.texts_to_matrix(test[['comment']], mode='count'), maxlen=max_length, padding='post')
y_test = np.array([[float(d)] for d in test[['score']].pop('score')]).T
embedding_vecor_length = 128
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=max_length))
model.add(Convolution1D(64, 3, padding='same'))
model.add(Convolution1D(32, 3, padding='same'))
model.add(Convolution1D(16, 3, padding='same'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(95692,activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(95692,activation='sigmoid'))
tensorBoardCallback = TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs', write_graph=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3, callbacks=[tensorBoardCallback])
```

Comment: Have you read [TensorFlow: Dst tensor is not initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313818/tensorflow-dst-tensor-is-not-initialized)? Run the code after reducing the `max_length`.

Comment: I have tried that, reducing the batch_size to all different numbers (even 1), reducing the vocabulary length, and only doing one convolution, but I get the same error.

Comment: I am not seeing anything wrong with your code. If you are still facing this problem, you should file a github issue, preferably with some minimal code to reproduce this.