# Keras & Tensorflow GPU Out of Memory on Large Image Data

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, classification

I'm building an image classification system with Keras, Tensorflow GPU backend and CUDA 9.1, running on Ubuntu  18.04.

I'm using a very large image data set with 1.2 million images, 15k classes, and is 335 GB in size.

I can train my network on 90,000 images with no problems.  However, when I scale up and use the entire data set of 1.2 million images I get the error shown below, which I believe have to do with running out of memory.

I'm using GeForce GTX 1080 with 11GB memory, and I have 128GB of RAM, 300GB of swap file and AMD Threadripper 1950X with 16 cores.

I followed the advice given to solve similar problems.  I'm now using [smaller batch size of 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313818/tensorflow-dst-tensor-is-not-initialized) or [even smaller](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/issues/38), and a [smaller dense inner layer](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5199) of 256, and I'm still getting the same error shown below before the first training epoch begins.

**[Update]:** I found out that The memory error happens during the VGG16 `predict_generator` call, even before my network is built or trained.  See code below.

First, warnings and Errors:

```
2018-05-19 20:24:01.255788: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:967] failed to alloc 5635855360 bytes on host: CUresult(304)
2018-05-19 20:24:01.255850: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 5635855360
```

Then exceptions:

```
2018-05-19 13:56:40.472404: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:680] Stats: 
Limit:                 68719476736
InUse:                 15548829696
MaxInUse:              15548829696
NumAllocs:                   15542
MaxAllocSize:             16777216

2018-05-19 13:56:40.472563: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:279] ****************************************************************************************************
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/welshamy/tools/anaconda/3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1322, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/welshamy/tools/anaconda/3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1307, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/home/welshamy/tools/anaconda/3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1409, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Dst tensor is not initialized.
     [[Node: block5_pool/MaxPool/_159 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_133_block5_pool/MaxPool", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bottleneck.py", line 37, in <module>
    bottleneck_features_train = model_vgg.predict_generator(train_generator_bottleneck)
  File "/home/welshamy/tools/anaconda/3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/welshamy/tools/anaconda/3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2510, in predict_generator
    outs = self.predict_on_batch(x)
  File "/home/welshamy/tools/anaconda/3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1945, in predict_on_batch
    outputs = self.predict_function(ins)
  File "/home/welshamy/tools/anaconda/3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2478, in __call__
    **self.session_kwargs)
  File "/home/welshamy/tools/anaconda/3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/welshamy/tools/anaconda/3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1135, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/welshamy/tools/anaconda/3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1316, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/home/welshamy/tools/anaconda/3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1335, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Dst tensor is not initialized.
     [[Node: block5_pool/MaxPool/_159 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_133_block5_pool/MaxPool", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Here is my code:

```python
import numpy as np
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras import applications
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 224, 224

train_data_dir = './train_sample'

epochs = 100
batch_size = 10

# Data preprocessing
# Pixel values rescaling from [0, 255] to [0, 1] interval
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

# Retrieve images and their classes for training set.
train_generator_bottleneck = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode=None,
    shuffle=False)


num_classes = len(train_generator_bottleneck.class_indices)

model_vgg = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

bottleneck_features_train = model_vgg.predict_generator(train_generator_bottleneck)
np.save('../models/bottleneck_features_train.npy', bottleneck_features_train)

train_data = np.load('../models/bottleneck_features_train.npy')
train_labels = to_categorical(train_generator_bottleneck.classes, num_classes=num_classes)


model_top = Sequential()
model_top.add(Flatten(input_shape=train_data.shape[1:]))
model_top.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model_top.add(Dropout(0.5))
model_top.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model_top.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='rmsprop',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

# Model saving callback
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='../models/bottleneck_features.h5', monitor='val_acc', verbose=1,
                               save_best_only=True)

# Early stopping
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, patience=5)

history = model_top.fit(
    train_data,
    train_labels,
    verbose=2,
    epochs=epochs,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    callbacks=[checkpointer, early_stopping],
    validation_split=0.3)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe the problem here is batch_size, as you mention it already is so low. Furthermore, because you said that it works for 90k images, the issue is probably that `train_data` cannot fit on the GPU in memory (which is needed at the start of each fit epoch). In order to alleviate this problem, you will need to fit your `model_top` with a `generator`, just as you get your features from `predict_generator`. One way you can do this is wrapping a generator class around `train_data`, but I would instead just connect the two models (note I could not test this, but I think it is right):

```python
model_vgg = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

model_top = Flatten()(model_vgg)
model_top = Dense(256, activation='relu')(model_top)
model_top = Dropout(0.3)(model_top)
model_top = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(model_top)

model = Model(inputs=model_vgg.inputs, outputs=model_top)

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='rmsprop',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

# Model saving callback
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='../models/bottleneck_features.h5', monitor='val_acc', verbose=1,
                               save_best_only=True)

# Early stopping
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, patience=5)

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_data,
    train_labels,
    verbose=2,
    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    callbacks=[checkpointer, early_stopping],
    ...)
```

I changed `categorical_crossentropy` to `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` so that just indexes can be sent as the labels, otherwise the same. You will need to supply steps_per_epoch as the length of the training data / the batch size. Or just put whatever number to test. I also used the keras functional api to make this more clear.

This would also allow the weights of the VGG top to change in order to help you classify better. If this is not what you want for some reason, you can freeze it by iterating over all of the vgg layers and setting `trainable` to false.

lmk if it works.

Comment: Thanks @modesitt .  I ran your code with `steps_per_epoch` set as you suggested and got the same error.  I also tried your code while setting Tensorflow configs to limit GPU memory use with `config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True`  and `config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.7` and passing them to `set_session(tf.Session(config=config))` with no luck.  I may train on a sample of the data as a compromise.

Comment: hm @Wesam, that's strange. let me try stuff out