# How to feed a model using a generator in keras, tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence

When I was training my Tensorflow autoencoder on big datasets I started getting the error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.
```

It's probably because I don't have enough memory on my GPU. I read somewhere that I should create a generator and feed my model in batches to mitigate this issue:

```
def prepare_data(self, train_notes):
    train_notes_categorical = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(train_notes, dtype="float16").transpose(0, 2, 1)
    n_samples = train_notes_categorical.shape[0]
    n_notes = train_notes_categorical.shape[1]
    self.input_dim = n_notes * self.sequence_length
    train_notes_flattened = train_notes_categorical.reshape(n_samples, self.input_dim)
    self.tensor_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(tensors=(train_notes_flattened, train_notes_flattened))

def generate_data(self):
    for batch in self.tensor_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE):
        yield batch

def train(self):
    log = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=LOG),
    callbacks_list = [checkpoint, log]
    self.model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=RMSprop(learning_rate=0.01),
                       metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()])

    history = self.model.fit(self.generate_data(), epochs=EPOCHS, callbacks=callbacks_list, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
    self.model.save(os.path.join(MODEL_DIR_PATH, MODEL_NAME + "_" + CURR_DT + ".hdf5"))
```

However this doesn't seem to work, since I am getting the same error. What should I do to make this work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37313818/681865

Comment: this doesn't really answer my question

Comment: You can use `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` , to generate batches of tensor image data with real-time data augmentation. For more details on keras datagenerator look at this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator).