# InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from device:CPU:0 to device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

```
linux_user@server_machine:~/spatial/tuning_neighbors_7$ python3 *hyper*.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tuner_hyperband.py", line 209, in <module>
    load_data_k(
  File "tuner_hyperband.py", line 127, in load_data_k
    tz = tf.convert_to_tensor(data_z, np.float32)
  File "/home/linux_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/home/linux_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 106, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.
linux_user@server_machine:~/spatial/tuning_neighbors_7$
```

What is the main reason for this error?

- Is it because of low disk space?
- Is it because of low RAM memory?
- Is it because of an engaged GPU?

How to resolve this?

Comment: Most likely a lack of GPU memory. See also: [TensorFlow: Dst tensor is not initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37313818/7370153)

Answer (score 5):

It is because of GPU RAM memory is full (at least for my case).
Is that the full message? Because in my case it was quite longer (and clear it is a memory issue). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71766129/dataset-gets-re-copied-to-gpu-causing-out-of-memory-when-calling-to-eval-twice).

Some debugging tips:

1. You can use `tf.config.experimental.get_memory_info('GPU:0')['current'] / 10**9` to see the memory usage until a point.
2. At some point, tensorflow should tell you your available memory in a message like `Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 9058 MB memory`
3. If you are using numpy arrays that are converted into tensors or used in `fit`, `evaluate` or equivalent functions you can use `npa.size * npa.itemsize / 10**9` to know the size needed to create the new tensor.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code after load your libraries for increase your GPU read batch size:
This code is used to configure TensorFlow to work with GPUs.

First, it calls the tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') function to get a list of all the available physical GPUs on the system.

If GPUs are available, it sets the memory growth option for each GPU to True, which allows TensorFlow to allocate memory on the GPU dynamically as needed. It then calls tf.config.list_logical_devices('GPU') to get a list of all the logical GPUs on the system, which is the number of GPUs that TensorFlow can use.

Finally, it prints out the number of physical and logical GPUs available, and if an error occurs, it prints the error message.

```py
gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  try:
    # Currently, memory growth needs to be the same across GPUs
    for gpu in gpus:
      tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
    logical_gpus = tf.config.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
  except RuntimeError as e:
    # Memory growth must be set before GPUs have been initialized
    print(e)
```

Comment: while this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.