# I'm trying to run a basic CNN model, but tensorflow throws an internal error - Dst tensor is not initialized

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

**InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.**

**CODE**

```py
epochs = 1
batch_size = 1
OPTIMIZER = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1)

def binary_baseline_model():
    model = Sequential([
        Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer="he_normal", 
               input_shape=(img_size[0], img_size[1], 1)),
        Flatten(),
        Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer="he_normal")
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer=OPTIMIZER,
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

binary_baseline_model = binary_baseline_model()

binary_baseline_model.summary()

# Fitting the model (training and validation phase in multiple epochs)
history = binary_baseline_model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split = 0.2, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size,
                                    shuffle=True, verbose = 2)
```

Comment: Tried reducing batch sizes even to 1 and epoch 1 but still getting the same error. The same code worked before but now after reinstalling python and tensorflow to newer versions, it is taking too much RAM and throwing OOM error and when I rerun it, it throws this internal error.

Comment: I'm using GTX 1060 6gb, so running a simple CNN shouldn't be a problem. My current python version is 3.9.7 , tensorflow 2.7.0, cudNN 8.1 for cuda 11.2 as per tensorflow gpu support page. Python and tensorflow installed in a conda virtual environment and cuda libraries are in path.

Comment: Different solutions tried:
# TO fix GPU memory issues
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)

reduced gpu memory and ram but getting same error if I increase batch size more than 1

Comment: printout X_train.shape and y_train.shape

Comment: The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313818/tensorflow-dst-tensor-is-not-initialized) to this problem was posted earlier. This might be helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.